# How to programmatically change current Principal in Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

How do I change my the current user that is currently login in the application?

Here's the code that I use to switch the current user to it's another account/relative account.

```
   User user = userService.getUser(dependentId);

        String access_token = authorizationToken.replace("Bearer","").trim();

        if(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() != null) {
           User relative = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
            for(Role role: relative.getRoles()) {
                if(role.getName().equals("PATIENT")) {
                    OAuth2Authentication oauth2 = defaultTokenServices.loadAuthentication(access_token);

                    User o3 =(User)SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                            .getAuthentication()
                            .getPrincipal();

                    Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user,
                            user.getPassword()
                            ,user.getAuthorities());

                    OAuth2Authentication oAuth2Authentication = new OAuth2Authentication(oauth2.getOAuth2Request(),authentication);

                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(oAuth2Authentication);

                    User o5  = (User)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
                    break;
                }
            }
```

I ran the code on my debugger, I am expecting `o5` to be a different object  from o3 but they  are still the same

Comment: Does `oAuth2Authentication.getPrincipal()`differ from o3 right before setting the new Authentication to the SecurityContext?

Comment: How it will become change...you are taking the same object and setting same again..new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user,
                            user.getPassword()
                            ,user.getAuthorities());....create token with different user object or roles..